# interpolation of missing values, not NA

Tags: python, pandas

i want to interpolate (Linear interpolation) data. but There is no NA.

Here is my data.with many missing values.

| timestamp | id | strength |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1383260400000 | 1 | -0.3803901328171995 |
| 1383261000000 | 1 | -0.42196042219455937 |
| 1383265200000 | 1 | -0.460714706261982 |

My expected :

| timestamp | id | strength |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1383260400000 | 1 | -0.3803901328171995 |
| 1383261000000 | 1 | -0.42196042219455937 |
| 1383261600000 | 1 | Linear interpolated data |
| 1383262200000 | 1 | Linear interpolated data |
| 1383262800000 | 1 | Linear interpolated data |
| 1383263400000 | 1 | Linear interpolated data |
| 1383264000000 | 1 | Linear interpolated data |
| 1383264600000 | 1 | Linear interpolated data |
| 1383265200000 | 1 | -0.460714706261982 |

timestamp starts 1383260400000, ends 1383343800000
and another id(from 1 to 2025) has same issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea is create datetimes, convert to `DatetimeIndex` and in lambda function add missing datetimes by [`Series.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.asfreq.html) with interpolate:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')

f = lambda x: x.asfreq('10Min').interpolate()
df = df.set_index('timestamp').groupby('id')['strength'].apply(f).reset_index()
print (df)
   id           timestamp  strength
0   1 2013-10-31 23:00:00 -0.380390
1   1 2013-10-31 23:10:00 -0.421960
2   1 2013-10-31 23:20:00 -0.427497
3   1 2013-10-31 23:30:00 -0.433033
4   1 2013-10-31 23:40:00 -0.438569
5   1 2013-10-31 23:50:00 -0.444106
6   1 2013-11-01 00:00:00 -0.449642
7   1 2013-11-01 00:10:00 -0.455178
8   1 2013-11-01 00:20:00 -0.460715
```

Last if need original format of timestamps:

```
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].astype(np.int64) // 1000000

print (df)
   id      timestamp  strength
0   1  1383260400000 -0.380390
1   1  1383261000000 -0.421960
2   1  1383261600000 -0.427497
3   1  1383262200000 -0.433033
4   1  1383262800000 -0.438569
5   1  1383263400000 -0.444106
6   1  1383264000000 -0.449642
7   1  1383264600000 -0.455178
8   1  1383265200000 -0.460715
```

EDIT:

```
#data from question
df =pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': [1383260400000, 1383261000000, 1383265200000], 
                  'id': [1, 1, 1], 
                  'strength':[-0.3803901328171995,-0.4219604221945593,-0.460714706261982]})
    
print (df)
       timestamp  id  strength
0  1383260400000   1 -0.380390
1  1383261000000   1 -0.421960
2  1383265200000   1 -0.460715
```

Solution create for each `id` all datetimes by [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) and create missing values by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `MultiIndex`, last per `id` is used interpolate:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')

r = pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime(1383260400000, unit='ms') , 
                  pd.to_datetime(1383343800000, unit='ms'), 
                  freq='10Min')

ids = df['id'].unique()

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([r, ids], names=['timestamp','id'])
f = lambda x: x.interpolate()
df = (df.set_index(['timestamp', 'id'])
        .reindex(mux)
        .groupby('id')['strength']
        .transform(f)
        .reset_index())

print (df)
              timestamp  id  strength
0   2013-10-31 23:00:00   1 -0.380390
1   2013-10-31 23:10:00   1 -0.421960
2   2013-10-31 23:20:00   1 -0.427497
3   2013-10-31 23:30:00   1 -0.433033
4   2013-10-31 23:40:00   1 -0.438569
..                  ...  ..       ...
135 2013-11-01 21:30:00   1 -0.460715
136 2013-11-01 21:40:00   1 -0.460715
137 2013-11-01 21:50:00   1 -0.460715
138 2013-11-01 22:00:00   1 -0.460715
139 2013-11-01 22:10:00   1 -0.460715

[140 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: ID should be produced at 1383260400000 to 1383343800000, if there is no value, it's 0. not just interpolation. can you do it?

Comment: and, when 
    df4['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['timestamp'], unit='ms'), valueerror occured, non convertible value with the unit 'ms'

Comment: @bamtu - what is `print (df4['timestamp'].head().tolist())` ? What means `if there is no value, it's 0` - it means `strength is 0` for non existing datetimes? Or something else?

Comment: @bamtu - added datetime between `1383260400000, 1383343800000` per `id` and interpolate per `id` in answer by `EDIT`

Comment: df3 = pd.read_csv('C:\DATASET\MI_01_accu_test.txt', delimiter='\t', lineterminator='\r', low_memory=False)
df3.columns = ["timestamp", "id", "strength"]
df4 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["timestamp", "id", "strength"])

Comment: print (df4['timestamp'].head().tolist()) is
['\n1383260400000', '\n1383261000000', '\n1383265200000', '\n1383265800000', '\n1383269400000']

Comment: @bamtu - can you try change `df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')` to `df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'].str.strip(), unit='ms')` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244652/discussion-between-bamtu-and-jezrael).